# Read from text file, capture text, write to another text file in specific syntax

Tags: readfile

I have a text file A with the following syntax:

```
Attribute_Name, 'Path', 'Tutorial';
Attribute_Name2, 'Path2', 'Tutorial';
....
```

What I need to do is to read from that file, capture those 3 values: Attribute Name, Path and Project Name (tutorial in that case) and write it to output text file, B with the following syntax:

```
DELETE ATTRIBUTE "Atribute_Name" IN FOLDER "Path" FROM PROJECT "Tutorial";
```

and repeat for as many iterations as there are lines in the input file.

What is the best(easiest) language to implement that? Can anyone provide example code for that?

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally do something like that with Perl, because I'm familiar with Perl and it works great for these kinds of tasks. You can also write a sed one-liner to get that done.

If you're not a fan of Perl, any modern dynamic language should let you get the job done with minimal effort.

EDIT: An example Perl script (full file for readability) would look like this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (my $line = <>) {
    $line =~ /^\s*(.+?), '(.+?)', '(.+?)';$/; # Doesn't handle internal escaping
    print "DELETE ATTRIBUTE \"$1\" IN FOLDER \"$2\" FROM PROJECT \"$3\";\n";
}
```

[See the result](http://ideone.com/lAROKl#).